# Heroku Ruby Application Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3

I keep running into an application error on my Heroku Ruby app: feedimg.heroku.com
The app works fine on localhost and I tried `heroku rake db:migrate`, `heroic restart` re-connect/set up AWS S3, none of them works.

Here is the error log:

```
2016-09-22T06:04:13.332269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=feedimg.herokuapp.com request_id=6b563da0-56ff-49bd-aa26-9769ca3ee4bd fwd="199.188.193.230" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-22T06:05:49.099162+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=feedimg.herokuapp.com request_id=15478003-112f-4048-a0a1-4f5c05953fd3 fwd="199.188.193.230" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Do you have any other logging service (papertail, loggly, new relic) or error reporting tool (rollbar, airbrake) in place? Does the app work on your development machine? Are the test still green?

Comment: I only have Device gem as the logging service. I don't have any other error reporting tool in place. It does work on my local dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart `heroku`

```
heroku restart
```

Comment: I have tried `heroku restart`, but the error persists.

Comment: try `heroku run rake fb:migrate`

Comment: config.after_initialize do
      ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate(Rails.root.join("db/migrate"), nil)
 end \n
Add this line of code to auto execute migration on initialise in application.rb to resolve migration issue